# Assign xpath->query and read length in one step

Tags: php, xpath

Why is this not allowed? (I get a syntax error at the `->length`):

`($x=$xpath->query($s))->length`

According to the http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php the value of an assignment expression is the value assigned, but it does not seem to work when assigning the result of a xpath->query.

I want to use the expression in a while loop, where I'm assigning the query result and checking for zero-length in one step:

```
// $xpath is a DOMXPATH object
while(($x=$xpath->query($s))->length){
    // do something with $x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in anyway a PHP expert, but from what I observed, it is combination of the parentheses and *object operator* (`->`) that triggers the error. The assignment expression itself correctly returns an instance of `DOMNodeList`, as we expect given the linked documentation :

```
$xml = "<person><name>John-Doe</name></person>";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$test = ($x = $xpath->query("/person/foo"));
//$test contains instance of `DOMNodeList` on which we can use `->` to get the length
echo $test->length;

//but using `->` on parentheses triggers the initial error :
echo ($test)->length;
```

To achieve the actual goal, you maybe able to use plain `for` loop, which provides more flexibility in controlling the loop, instead of using `while`. Something along the lines of the following snippet :

```
for($x=$xpath->query($s);
    $x->length;
    $x=$xpath->query($s))
{
    //do something with $x
}
```

I assume that *`$xpath->query($s)` result* changes in the next iterations, in a way that `$x->length` value decreases, so that the loop will eventually terminates.

Comment: Yes, the `$xpath->query($s)` result changes in next iteration, yes, $x->length becoms zero, and yes, it is not a probleme for me to solve it in an other way, I just think that the `($x=$xpath->query($s))->length`-solution is much more elegant

Comment: @KurtLarsen It looks like the syntax of form `(...)->` is not allowed. But I couldn't find anything that confirm or contradict this so far. My point is, this case doesn't contradict the documentation you linked to. The problem is in another part of the snippet.